# How to deserialize XML node to pojo in Java?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax

Say i have a very large XML file that contains thousands of nodes  that contain all kinds of details, something like:

```
<Document>
    <Header>
    </Header>
    <Whatever>
        <Person>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Age>30</Age>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
            <Age>30</Age>
        </Person>
        ...
    </Whatever>
</Document>
```

I want to stream the xml file, and each time it hits a Person node, it should give me a Person pojo. With StAX i can do that by creating the pojo manually, but i'm betting there are libraries out there that do that for me.

Comment: You can use https://jaxb.java.net/ but you will need to provide an xml schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a class like:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "Age")
    int age;
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Header {    
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Document {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
    Header header;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Whatever")
    @XmlElement(name = "person")
    List<Person> people;
}
```

After use JAXB for unmarshalling xml to object.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Document document = (Document) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

List<Person> people = document.getPeople();
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the xml file can be 10 GB big, i don't want to keep everything in memory.

Comment: In case your file is big or your memory is low, the best way is using StAX parser

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Java program that scans through the XML file and each time it comes across the String `<Person>` starts saving the subsequent Strings until it reaches `</Person>`.

Once a String like `<Person>....</Person>` has been extracted - use a library such [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) to convert it to a Java object.